# Prime numbers falling in the gap between twice the members of twin primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Frequently, the gap between twice a pair of twin primes contains a prime number. That is, for $p_i,(p_i+2)\in \mathbb P$, it is often but not always the case that one of $2p_i+1$ or $2p_i+3$ is also prime. In fact, for $p_i=29$ both $59,61$ (another pair of twin primes) are prime.

I looked at the first sixty pairs of twin primes (by hand; I'm not a programmer). What I observed is that the number of instances in which a gap between twice a pair of twin primes fails to feature a prime tends to increase as the size of the twin primes increases, but the effect is not particularly rapid. $p_i$ for which $(p_i+2)\in \mathbb P$ and neither $2p_i+1$ nor $2p_i+3$ are also prime include: $71,103,107,109,149,311,347,461,521,569,821,857,881,1061,1091,1151,1301,1319,1487,1619,1667,1697,1721,1787,1871,1877,1949$

**Minor question:** Are there other instances where $p_i,(p_i+2)\in \mathbb P$, and both $2p_i+1$ and $2p_i+3$ are also prime?

Refinements to Bertrand's Postulate suggest that for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, there is always a value $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$ there is a prime $p$ in the gap $n<p<(1+\epsilon)n$. Various formulations of $\epsilon$ with regard to various values of $n_0$ have been advanced. In the case I am looking at, $\epsilon = \frac{2}{p_i}$ which gets arbitrarily small as $p_i$ gets large. Depending on how rapidly the value of $\epsilon$ in my scenario diminishes compared to other evaluations of $\epsilon$, it might become the case that the gaps I am discussing either must always or may never contain a prime number. With regard to the 'must always' option, the data at small values of $p_i$ run counter to it in that primeless gaps occur and appear to increase in frequency as $p_i$ increases.

**Main question:** Is there a number $n_0$, such that $p_i>n_0$, $(p_i+2)\in \mathbb P$, and one of $2p_i+1$ or $2p_i+3$ must be prime?

Comment: "how rapidly the value of $\epsilon$ ... diminishes" - In the generalized Bertrand postulate, $\epsilon$ does not diminish *at all* (in the original Bertrand postulate, $\epsilon=1$ does not diminish either)

Comment: In the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate
in the section 'Better results' it gives successively lower values for $\epsilon$ as $n_0$ increases. Perhaps my wording was inelegant, but my understanding is that no matter how small one chooses to set $\epsilon$, one can find a range $n>n_0$ where $n<p<(1+\epsilon)n$. I interpret that to imply that if one goes to larger $n$, one is free to choose smaller $\epsilon$. That is what I meant by 'diminish.'

Comment: $659$ and $809$ work

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Great find! Thanks.

Comment: I've added another one. But all I'm using is a table of primes with integers down the page and $1,3,7,9$ across which could be accessible on the web if you wish to find any more.

Comment: Check out Sophie Germain prime, Cunningham chain, and Safe prime.

Comment: @John Nicholson Thanks for that informative suggestion.

Comment: See COMMENTS for https://oeis.org/A168421 "For some n and k". Note that no one has done anything with this new math.